# How do I import built-in Wix Dialogs?

Tags: wix

I've inherited a Wix project. I don't know how it was compiled before, all I have are the source `.wxs` and `.wxi` files. I'm using `candle` and `light` from the command line to compile and link.

So far, I can `candle` my `wxs` files to `wixobj` files without error, however when I try and run `light`, I get a lot of errors similar to:

```
C:\wix\FeatureTree.wxs(39) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference 
                                              to symbol 'Dialog:ErrorDlg' in 
                                              section 'Fragment:'.
```

I've done some reading, and it seems that the line that's causing this error:

```
<DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
```

I've got the following line at the top of the Fragment:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
```

Is just trying to import a built-in Wix error dialog. Why is it failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the library from the `light` command, which needs to be specified with `-ext`:

```
light -ext WixUIExtension *.wixobj -o installer.msi
```

Answer (score 2):

Or from Visual Studio Wix project, add a reference to WixUIExtension.dll